# Why we limit length of columns values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

When we creating database for our application, We limited lengths of database columns.

example -

1. String (200)
2. int (5)

etc

Is there any effect on Speed or some effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, one does not limit the length of a "database". Instead, one does limit the size of columns of tables in a database.

Why do we do this, you ask?

1. We don't want to waste any space for data that's never going to use it (that's what the varchar, varbinary and the like are for).
2. It's a best practice because it forces you to think of your data structure BEFORE you actually use it.
3. The less data there is the faster the processing of the application (that's a tautology).
4. It makes it easier to validate your data if you know exactely how much space it is allowed to take.
5. Full text indexes gain greatly when limited in size

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can think of is, When you didn't specify the length of a column data type, the MYsql engine would assume a default length value that may be a lot larger of the length of the actual data that would be stored in that column. So it is always a best practice never to ignore the length property of a column.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the length of database fields ensures validation of data, you won't get any unexpected data of a length other than what has been specified. Also certain fields cannot be indexed such as LONG so choose appropriately and wisely. With regard to performance the effect is negligible. You need to also think about the data itself, for example storing data in a unicode encoding such as UTF-8 may increase the storage requirements.